# R aov and statistical analysis interpretation

Tags: r, anova

I have the following dataset and I would like to see if for each given classeT, Reco_mean is significantly different from one year to another, and this for each classeR. I am not sure which statistical model I should use for this analysis as i am still not familiar with statsistical models.

[image]

I tried the following code as one example:

```
    if (data1$classeR == 0 && data1$classeT == 12.7) {fit  <- aov(Reco_mean~year, data=data1)}
```

But I would like to do this for the 2 classeR and the different classeT (probably without using the if condition).

Then how can I interpret the aov results. I would like to be able to say: the difference of each Reco_mean for one classeR and classeT is not significantly different from one year to another. Should I use a specific test for that to compare each Reco_mean?

Many thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: You should probably create one model that includes `classeR` and `classeT` and do a post-hoc test.

Comment: thanks Roland. Do you mean something like > fit  <- aov(Reco_mean~year + classeR + classeT, data= data1) or fit  <- aov(Reco_mean~year * classeR * classeT, data= data1) ? and then a pairwise.t.test ?

Comment: Student's T is the way to check if the means of two distributions are the same.  F-test tells you if the standard deviations are the same.  Shouldn't you be using standard statistical tests?